# NSFileManager not saving Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am trying to save data into a directory created by NSFileManager but when I try and retrieve the data and NSLog it I get null. Also, when you create a directory does that mean you create a folder at a specified url path? Heres the code I am using

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *urlsArray = [manager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSLog(@"%@", urlsArray);
// This will create a new url and append a photo title to the end
NSURL *url = [[urlsArray lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.recentPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE]]];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [url absoluteString]];
NSLog(@"%@", urlString);
//create the directory
if(![manager fileExistsAtPath:urlString isDirectory:YES]){
    BOOL success = [manager createDirectoryAtURL:url withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating data path: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
//get url for a photo image and then store it.
NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.recentPhoto format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[imageData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
//get data to check if its stored
NSData *checkImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
//This returns null
NSLog(@"%@", checkImageData);
//this returns 0
NSLog(@"%d", [manager isReadableFileAtPath:urlString]);
```

Comment: Try writing the NSData using the writeToURL:options:error: method and see if an error is returned--this might help you debug the problem.

Comment: would I just nslog the error then?

Comment: Yes.  Whenever there's an API that offers an NSError out param, it's good to use this and inspect the result so you can understand why it failed.  See one of the answers below for an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

This:

```
NSURL *url = [[urlsArray lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.recentPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE]]];
```

should be:

```
NSURL *url = [[urlsArray lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[self.recentPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE]];
```

This:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [url absoluteString]];
```

should be:

```
NSString *urlString = [url path];
```

This:

```
BOOL success = [manager createDirectoryAtURL:url withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

should be:

```
BOOL success = [manager createDirectoryAtURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

This:

```
[imageData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
```

should be:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL res = [imageData writeToURL:url options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (!res) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to write to %@: %@", url, error);
}
```

The primary issue was the use of `absoluteString` instead of `path` to convert the URL to a file path. Secondary was passing the filename instead of the path when creating the directory. The needless use of `stringWithFormat:` didn't cause any issues but please break that habit now. Only use `stringWithFormat:` when you actually need to format a string. It is NOT needed to assign a string to a string variable.

Comment: +1 about `stringWithFormat:`... I heard somewhere that a recent version of Xcode was supposed to be able to pick this up (where `stringWithFormat:` is given `@"%@"` as the format string and only a string as the argument).

Comment: My code works now thanks but just some questions, I don't end up using urlString which had the absoluteString so would that still be a problem? What is wrong with using absoluteString instead of path? Also, is a directory similiar to a file? I am just a bit confused about directories

Comment: `path` converts the file URL into a path. `absoluteString` simply gives a string representation of the URL (which would be something like "file:///somepath/to/the/file"). A file is the actual content. A directory (or folder) is a collection of files.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a file name for your image inside the directory, this can be solved by adding this line right after the directory is created :

```
    // Right after the directory is created (I suppose the format is png) :
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];

    // Now you can continue with the rest of your code :

    //get url for a photo image and then store it.
    NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.recentPhoto format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    [imageData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
    //get data to check if its stored
    NSData *checkImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //This returns null
    NSLog(@"%@", checkImageData);
    //this returns 0
    NSLog(@"%d", [manager isReadableFileAtPath:urlString]);
```

Comment: I added this line but I still get null when I try and retrieve the data?

Comment: what do you get as urlString (before creating the folder) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never created an instance of a file manager.  I have always simply used the default.
See if this helps:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```